# partition of an IEnumerable sequence

Tags: .net, f#

Say I'm interating over a seq, using for..in..do and an exception is thrown midway. How do I get a 'pointer' to the place in the sequence I last read from.

For example, I want to print what's remaining in the sequence after the exception is raised.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let s = seq { 1;2;3;5;6 }
exception MyEx of IEnumerator<int>

try 
    let mutable count = 0
    for item in s do
        printfn "%d" item
        if count = 1 then
            printfn "raising exception"
            raise (MyEx (s.GetEnumerator()))
        count <- count + 1
with
| MyEx ex ->
    while ex.MoveNext() do
        printfn "%d" ex.Current
```

I could rewrite it using the enumerator explicitly and MoveNext() and pass the enumerator to the exception constructor but I want to know if there is a way to do it using the for .. in .. do

Comment: Just use a for loop with index access. Or move `let mutable count = 0` outside the try catch block, then you should be able to continue from `count` index.

Comment: @Charles I want to know if there's a way to do it without arrays, i.e. using for..in..do as it is in the question, without a mutable index.

Comment: But where does the Exception occur, on MoveNext? on Current? If its inside the block then just move your try catch inside the loop body.

Comment: As far i know, it's not possible. But IEnumerator don't throw exceptions as far i know. At least never encountered it. Maybe you want to achieve something else. Or in another words: Is this a question with a **XY Problem**?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is likely that there is a simpler solution to the problem you are actually trying to solve (most likely, you can avoid exceptions altogether).

However, if (most likely too) creative solution to the problem would be to use a custom computation expression. The following is a very incomplete implemntation that has a special `for` operation which automatically checks for exceptions in the body and wraps them in `ForLoopException` with also captures the rest of the sequence:

```
exception ForLoopException of exn * seq<obj>

type AutoSeqBuilder() = 
  member x.For(s:seq<'a>, f) =
    use en = s.GetEnumerator() 
    let rec loop() = 
      if en.MoveNext() then
        try f en.Current
        with e ->
          let rest = seq {
            yield box en.Current 
            while en.MoveNext() do yield box en.Current }
          raise(ForLoopException(e, rest))
        loop ()
    loop()
  member x.Zero() = ()
  member x.Combine(a, b) = a; b()
  member x.Delay(f) = f
  member x.Run(f) = f()
  member x.TryWith(f, g) =
    try f() with e -> g e

let serr = AutoSeqBuilder()
```

Now you can use the `serr` computation builder to do something like this:

```
serr { 
  try 
    for i in 0 .. 10 do
      if i > 5 then failwith "Too much" 
      printfn "Processing %d" i
  with ForLoopException(e, rest) ->
    for v in rest do
      printfn "Failed or skipped %O" v }
```